# Join two DataFrame with different key column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

i want to join courseFee Dataframe with febReg DataFrame. But both of them have different key column name. For courseFee is 'CID' and febReg is 'course_id'. Why in this code i can't join with only use left_on= and right_on= parameter?

code

```
import pandas as pd

folder = r'C:\Users\pulun\hbrag08\Durga Software\Complete Python Package\Python for Data Science\04. Pandas\DataFrame'
studentDataScr = folder+r'\\student_data.csv'
courseFeeScr = folder+r'\\course_fee.csv'
febRegScr = folder+r'\\february_registration.csv'
janResScr = folder+r'\\january_registration.csv'


def csvReader(fileName, delimiter, *args,):
    x = None
    n = None

    if len(args) == 1:
        for i in args:
            x = i
        n = None
    else:
        x = args
        n = x[0]

    return pd.read_csv(fileName,
                       usecols=x,
                       index_col=n,
                       sep=delimiter)


studentData = csvReader(studentDataScr, ';', 'student_id',
                        'student_name', 'gender', 'mobile_number', 'email')
courseFee = csvReader(courseFeeScr, ';', 'course_id', 'course_name', 'fee')
regColumn = ['student_id', 'course_id']

janReg = csvReader(janResScr, ';', regColumn)
febReg = csvReader(febRegScr, ';', regColumn)

courseFee.rename(columns={'course_id': 'CID'}, inplace=True)

joinTwo = pd.merge(courseFee, febReg, left_on='CID', right_on='course_id')
print(joinTwo.head())
```

error output

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'CID'
```

Comment: We need to be able to reproduce your problem to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks for your advice, i am so new here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the `csvReader` function is supposed to do exactly, but it's incorrectly built.

By packing `*args` and passing a list as parameter, `args` will be a tuple of a single item: your list, and `n` will always be None.

Either rewrite the function, or pass the unpacked list:

```
janReg = csvReader(janResScr, ';', *regColumn)
```

Secondly, passing `usecols` does **not** mean that your data will necessarily have those columns. If they are absent in the dataset, they won't be there. I'm fairly sure that there is no `course_id` column in the file in the first place. So renaming won't do anything, and `merge` will fail.

Comment: i am a newbie here. csvReader function is used because i have just learn about function in Python. So rather than using read_csv() and another parameter. I choose to create ones.

course_id is there in my file, because it only have two columns, the course_id and student_id.

Answer (score 0):

this line of code save me. First i need to reset the index, then i need to rename the columns.

```
courseFee.reset_index(inplace=True)
courseFee.rename(columns={'course_id': 'CID'}, inplace=True)
```